# Which word is better for use and why: Datasheet or data sheet & Timesheet or time sheet

Tags: meaning, grammar, word-usage

Which word is better for use and why?

1) Datasheet or data sheet,
See Both Examples:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Datasheet, http://www.prb.org/Publications/Datasheets.aspx

2) Timesheet or time sheet,
See Both Examples:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timesheet,
http://www.miraclesalad.com/webtools/timesheet.php

3) Tasksheet or task sheet

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The words that you are asking about will, in all likelihood, be spelled as one word in the coming years, and future generations will look back and wonder why we didn't spell Data Sheet as Datasheet.  Personally, I would choose Time Sheet and Data Sheet because I see Time as a noun functioning as an adjective defining Sheet; similarly Car Wash, Computer Screen, or Table Cloth.

For example, I always thought "tomorrow" was one word but in the Great Gatsby it is spelled "to morrow" along with several other words which are now spelled as one word.

My observation about words such as yours is that for a while there is debate about the "correct" way to write or spell them and then after a few years the "correct" way is adopted and it seems that one word spellings usually win.